# Alamofire DidFinishCollectingMetrics Crash

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire, nsurlsession

I have an application that consists of listing page and detail page. Pressing the back button on the navigation repeatedly before the detail request is completed. Alamofire is also experiencing this crash.

This is my full log:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[APMURLSessionDelegateProxy URLSession:task:didFinishCollectingMetrics:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282842000'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x180817d1c 0x19803cee4 0x1808e875c 0x1807b135c 0x1807b082c 0x180f84aa8 0x114b9c700 0x114b9dfc8 0x114ba5150 0x114ba5e10 0x114bb163c 0x1dbc20e10 0x1dbc2093c)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[APMURLSessionDelegateProxy URLSession:task:didFinishCollectingMetrics:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282842000'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
23DF-26B4-45FA-95D9-D270455FA2D
```

Weak connections were made to in closures so that there is no memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're using an analytics or other framework that is interposing itself into the `URLSession` that Alamofire uses under the hood. You need to find out where the `APMURLSessionDelegateProxy` comes from, as it seems like it doesn't properly implement the `URLSessionTaskMetrics` delegate method, causing the crash. Perhaps there's an update for that framework that fixes the issue, or you can report the issue to get it fixed.

Comment: Thanks, This helps me to understand and fix my issue. In my case, SplunkMint caused the issue.